# How to calculate total and subtotal prices from regular prices on cart page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to modify original calculation of Totals and Subtotals on Magento cart page. I need to calculate them from Regular prices (no promo rules applied on that prices). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_product->getPrice()` instead of `$_product->getFinalPrice()`.

You can find more in:

- `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it, it is located in

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php** on line 115

done by replacing

- $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty());

with this

- $finalPrice = $product->getPrice($quoteItem->getQty());